Shadcn UI Initialization Fails with tailwind.config.ts in Next.js 15 Project Using TypeScript
I'm encountering issues while integrating Shadcn UI into a freshly created Next.js 15 project with TypeScript. Even though I followed the standard steps, I am getting errors related to tailwind.config.ts and missing files. Here's the breakdown:

Tailwind Config Issue:
Shadcn UI fails during initialization, expecting tailwind.config.js instead of the tailwind.config.ts that I have in my project. However, when I run npx tailwindcss --config tailwind.config.ts, everything works perfectly.

Missing Files and Folders:
The initialization process also asks for a src folder and index.css, but my project is configured with a global.css file, and I deliberately opted not to use a src directory during setup.


Steps i took:
Created a Next.js project with the following settings:
npx create-next-app@latest my-app
During the setup:
Would you like to use TypeScript? Yes
Would you like to use ESLint? Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? Yes
Would you like your code inside a src/ directory? No
Would you like to use App Router? Yes
Would you like to use Turbopack for next dev? Yes
Would you like to customize the import alias (@/* by default)? No
Initialized Shadcn UI:
npx shadcn@latest init
Observed Behavior:
Initialization fails, looking for tailwind.config.js instead of the TypeScript config.
It also requests a src folder and index.css, but my project uses global.css and has no src directory.
Environment:
Node.js 18+
Next.js 15
TailwindCSS (latest version)
Shadcn UI (latest version)
